# Nested return inside React Native code is giving syntactical errors ( " : " expected)

Tags: typescript

This is code for a streamgraph I found on this source right here: https://observablehq.com/@jamila/streamgraph-transitions
I'm trying to incorporate it into my react native application

```
const bumps = {
  // Inspired by Lee Byron’s test data generator.
   bump(a, n) {
    const x = 1 / (0.1 + Math.random());
    const y = 2 * Math.random() - 0.5;
    const z = 10 / (0.1 + Math.random());
    for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      const w = (i / n - y) * z;
      a[i] += x * Math.exp(-w * w);
    }
  },


   return bumps(n, m) {
    const a = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i] = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < m; ++i) bump(a, n);
    return a;
  };
}
```

This is the code in question. I'm getting errors in this specific portion here :

```
 },


   return bumps(n, m) {
    const a = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i] = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < m; ++i) bump(a, n);
    return a;
  };
}
```

Why am I getting errors such as `',' expected` and `':' expected` ?

Comment: you're missing the keyword `function`... `return function bumps(..)`

Comment: that got rid of every error except the addition of the keyword function itself. 
Now the ` ':' expected ` is for adding the keyword function

Comment: You would probably benefit from following a javascript tutorial to learn the syntax better https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript

Comment: You're getting an error from the comma after the end of `bump`.  Honestly this nested function is confusing and weird and I recommend just having two separate functions, where `bumps` uses `bump`.